# Rails Localization with Interpolation, how to do with link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization

please help, im stuck:

I want to localize something like "Please contact support <%= mail_to 'support@mail.de' %> for more informations'.

But how to do?

I try something like:

```
<%= t('.contact_support', :mail => ______????) %>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
en:
  emails:
    contact_support: 'Please contact %{email}'

<%= t('.contact_support', :email => 'support@mail.de') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an entry in your translation like :

```
en:
  emails:
    contact_support: 'Please contact support@mail.de'
```

and then in your view :

```
<%= t('emails.contact_support') %>
```

Comment: I want to translate a sentence like: Please contact support <%= mail_to 'support@mail.de' %> for more informations', so the mail_to is in the middle of the text.

Comment: If  'Please contact support...' is another sentence that needs translation, i could be wrong, but i don't think that you can put it in the middle. However, you can just specify the email like a parameter, as you specify in your question. Maybe a good idea would be to use two different translations, one for string and one for email and construct the final string in a helper. I think this is how i would do it.